# How can I run certain code after the change (by useState's updater) to state has been applied successfully?

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I have a selectbox with a list of customers and a list of vehicles for that customer displayed below the selectbox. When customer in the selectbox gets changed I need to update the list of vehicles, and show loader until we have got a response with new vehicles from the server.
Loader is shown when `vehicles === null` (vehicles not loaded).

here is my code:

```
  const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setting vehicles to null to show the loader
    setVehicles(null);
    axios
      .get(`/vehicles?customerId=${customer.id}`)
      .then((response) => setVehicles(response.data));
  }, [customer]);
```

It works just fine, but I am not sure if it's safe to fire the request without making sure that `vehicles` has actually got set to `null` first. Can it not theoretically happen that somehow `setVehicles(null)` gets executed after `setVehicles(response.data)` overwriting the state?

If so, how can I deal with this situation? I can't find a way to provide `.then` to the `setVehicles` or pass a callback to it like it's possible to do with class-based components.
I can probably just call `setVehicles(null)` when customer gets changed without firing request, and then have another `useEffect` monitoring changes to `vehicles`, and fire a request to load vehicles when `vehicle` gets set to `null`. But it feels unnecessarily complicated so I wonder if there is a better way to do it? Or can I just leave the code as it is hoping that because `setVehicles(null)` got scheduled first its state should always be applied before `setVehicles(response.data)`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't call setVehicles(null) after data is retrieved, unless you want for it to disappear immediately. Also, I wouldn't use null to trigger loader. if there is no data retrieved it will show loader forever.

Comment: I guess even if I had a separate `showLoader` variable for the loader I would still have the same problem though:
```
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowLoader(true);
    axios
      .get(`/vehicles?customerId=${customer.id}`)
      .then((response) => setVehicles(response.data))
      .then(() => setShowLoader(false));
  }, [customer]);
```
^^ Here there is still theoretically a chance that `setShowLoader(true)` will update the state after `setShowLoader(false)`, isn't there? Causing the loader to be displayed even though nothing is being loaded

Comment: If 'customer' variable changes, useEffect will run again and it will setShowLoader to true until data is retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have race condition with consecutive `setState` in same `useEffect`. To avoid this issue you would have indeed to break down and create another `useEffect`, you can't escape that.

Though, given your example, a race condition won't really happen. You have a `setState` that triggers only once the http request resolves, which takes sometime. That second state update can't realistically beat the first one that triggers right away.

Comment: what about two consecutive `setState`s right after one another? Like `setValue(true); setValue(false)`. Would the second one not always `win` because it got scheduled the latest?